# How to bypass this error to make the column zero if it is greater than the said date? " TypeError: invalid type promotion "

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, date, typeerror

```
df_main['month_1']= np.where(df_main['month_1'] >='2020-02-01',0,df_main['month_1'])
```

I need all the items in the month_1 column to be zero if the date is February 1st, 2020. 
I tried '02/01/2020' format as well, which doesn't work.

Comment: can you run `df_main.head()` and post the output?

Comment: what is the datatype of your column?

Comment: @kederrac datetime64[ns]

Comment: @kederrac the output is a series like this 

0       2019-05-01
1       2019-05-01
2       2019-05-01
3       2019-05-01

Comment: This might work better if the column dtype was object, so it could hold both dates and a number like 0.  Otherwise you risk setting the `0` to `'1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000'`.  Something in your expression is trying to convert number to date or the reverse (that is, some sort of `dtype` conversion).  Dates are tricky to handle right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your column datatype is timestamp you can not use str `'2020-02-01'` to compare with your column so you need also a timestamp value: `pd.Timestamp(2020, 2,1)`

you can use [pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df_main['month_1'] = df_main['month_1'].map(lambda x: 0 if x >= pd.Timestamp(2020, 2,1) else x)
```

or you can filter and assign:

```
df_main['month_1'][ df_main['month_1'] >= pd.Timestamp(2020, 2,1)] = 0
```

Comment: cannot compare timestamp with a str.

Comment: @SathyaBhat check now my answer